# How to handle the output of .jar file(which does not have any exit code with System.exit() ) in a batch file if the jar file throws an exception?

Tags: java, batch-file, jar

I have an existing very large number of .jar files and I'm supposed to catch if any exception arises and then need to call a different .jar file. This could have been done by catching the exception and setting an exit code and then checking in the batch file but there's a large number of .jar files.

JAR file looks this way:

```
public class FileProcessor{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
        }catch(Exception ex){
        //if error occurs, a mail gets send
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any alternative way without changing the .jar file and just work on the batch file.

Comment: See the comments on this question: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/20573/why-does-java-exit-with-success-after-an-uncaught-exception

Comment: The exceptions are printed in error stream so you can check if there something there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confident there isn't a trivial way to do this from a batch file.

However there may be a way to do it without editing the Java. Instead of calling into the jar directly from a batch file, you could call it from another Java application and use reflection to override the methods that have catch blocks that you need to set an exit code for.

This is probably more work than your suggestion and you may be better off editing the existing Java to behave as you want it to with exit codes.